# Getting werkzeug.routing.BuildError

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm getting a werkzeug.routing.BuildError when I go to my "login.html" page. The problem seems to be the "action=" attribute in the template. Originally it was `action={{url_for('login')}}`. Although the [docs show it done this way](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crash_course.html) it doesn't seem to work. When I change it to `action="/login"` or `action="#"` it works correctly. The question is why? I was under the impression that the correct way was the `action={{url_for('login')}}`?

Before I broke my code up into packages (everything in single py file) it worked correctly.

BTW, most of this code is from Miguel Grindberg's GREAT book "Flask Web Development". The code I'm having problems with is my own that I added going through the book. I'm on WinXP and using the most up to date Flask. Here is my code below:

`flasky\app\main\views.py`:

```
from flask import render_template, session, redirect, url_for, current_app, flash
from .. import db
from ..models import User
from ..email import send_email, post_mail
from . import main
from .forms import NameForm, RegForm


@main.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = RegForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['name'] = form.username.data
        session['logged_in'] = True
        return redirect(url_for('success'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

`flasky\app\templates\login.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    {{ super() }}

    <div class="well">
        <h1 align="center">Sign-In</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container"> 
        <form class="form form-horizontal" action="{{url_for('login')}}" method="post">
            {{form.hidden_tag()}}

            {{wtf.form_field(form.username)}}

            {{wtf.form_field(form.email)}}

            {{wtf.form_field(form.password)}}

            {{wtf.form_field(form.bool)}}

            {{wtf.form_field(form.submit)}}
        </form>
    </div>  
{% endblock %}

<!-- action= {{url_for('login')}} doesn't work. . ."#" and "\login" work-->
```

`flasky\app\main\forms.py`:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required, Email

class RegForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[Required()])
    email = StringField('Email Address', validators=[Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[Required()])
    bool = BooleanField("I Agree To Your Terms of Services", validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `BuildError` is raised when the `url_for()` method cannot locate an endpoint that fits the description.  In this case, no `login` endpoint was found to be registered with the Flask `app` object.

You appear to have registered the `login` route with a *Blueprint* named `main` instead; you need to use the blueprint name in the endpoint name:

```
{{ url_for('main.login') }}
```

If the template is only ever used by routes in the `main` blueprint, you can make it relative too by starting the name with a `.`:

```
{{ url_for('.login') }}
```

See the [*Building URLs* section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/#building-urls) of the Blueprints documentation.

Comment: Done! BTW, had I left it "action='\login'", would this have NOT worked in the long run even though it rendered the template?

Comment: Starting a path with ``\`` is not valid, you'd use `/login`; and since you have a blueprint, you could be changing the path of the blueprint from `/` to `/main/` or anything else, breaking your hardcoded path.

Comment: Oops, I meant "/login", sorry about that. Anyways, I understand and again, thank you very much.